# How is this regex wrong?

Tags: regex

I have a regex which I'm using to match **user functions** inside an IDE (Sublime). This matches what I want (the function name itself), but it also matches the first parentheses. Therefore the match is like follows:

this.**_myFunction(**'content');

Notice the opening paran.

Here is my expression:

```
(?:[^\._])?([\w-]+)(?:[\(]){1}
```

How can I exclude the opening paran from getting matched?

.

As a bonus question: How can I successfully **not** match the string: `function`, because as you can expect `function(` matches (not fun in JS).

Thank you to anyone who can assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot really use regex to parse any context-free grammar, but hopefully this can do better. It uses [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to not include the opening paren in the match but look for it anyways:

```
(?:[^\._])?([\w-]+)(?=[\(])
```

If your IDE's regex engine supports negative lookbehind (the subexpression is *not* found before the match), you can avoid matching the string 'function' or "function":

```
(?!<['"])(?:[^\._])?([\w-]+)(?=[\(])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?=pattern)`:

> A zero-width positive look-ahead assertion.  For example,
>                    "/\w+(?=\t)/" matches a word followed by a tab, without
>                    including the tab in $&.

So where you match your open paren wrap it in `(?=)` instead of `(?:)`